# Is there any onto homomorphism from $\mathbb{C}^*$ to $\mathbb{R}^*$?

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers, real-numbers, group-homomorphism

$\mathbb{C}^*$ be the multiplicative group of nonzero complex numbers similarly $\mathbb{R}^*$.
If so can you provide an example

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You need to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) for your question. Otherwise it just looks like you want somebody to do your homework for you; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, we will be happy to help.

Comment: What are your thoughts/guesses on this question?

Comment: Use $z\mapsto \vert z \vert$.

Comment: I know there does not exist an one-one homomorphism. So I was wondering about onto. I couldn't find any nor disprove it @GregMartin

Comment: But it is not onto @JensSchwaiger

Comment: Ok. I misread $\mathbb{R}^*$ as $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

Comment: Related (try the same method from the accepted answer for your question): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897212/does-there-exist-any-surjective-group-homomorphism-from-mathbb-r-onto?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that no such homomorphism exists. Assume that $\varphi\colon \mathbb{C}^*\to \mathbb{R}^*$ is a homomorhism. Take any $z\in \mathbb{C}^*$ and any $w\in \mathbb{C}^*$ such that $w^2=z$. (Every complex number has a square root.) Then $\varphi(z)=\varphi(w^2)=\varphi(w)^2>0$. Thus $\varphi(z)$ is always positive.